# The intersection '...' was reduced to never

Tags: typescript

I receive an event from an API with the type of event assigned to it. For each type of event there is a different schema, so I created a separate type for every event. The problem is, that Typescript reduces an intersection of events to `never`, because the property `type` is different for every event type. What should I do to avoid this error?

Here's a simplified code:

```
type EventType = 'login' | 'newMessage';

type ExampleEvent = {
  type: EventType;
  payload: unknown;
};

type LoginEvent = ExampleEvent & {
  type: 'login';
  payload: {
    userId: string;
  };
};

type NewMessageEvent = ExampleEvent & {
  type: 'newMessage';
  payload: {
    messageId: string;
  };
};

const loginEvent = {
  type: 'login',
  payload: {
    userId: 'abc',
  },
};

const newMessageEvent = {
  type: 'newMessage',
  payload: {
    messageId: 'abc',
  },
};

const events = [loginEvent, newMessageEvent];

const handlers = {
  login: (event: LoginEvent) =>
    console.log('user logged in', event.payload.userId),
  newMessage: (event: NewMessageEvent) =>
    console.log('new message', event.payload.messageId),
};

events.forEach(event => {
  // Argument of type '{ type: string; payload: { userId: string; }; } | { type: string; payload: { messageId: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  // The intersection '...' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
  // Type '{ type: string; payload: { userId: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  handlers[event.type as EventType](event);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you create your event types with using intersection, so your left side of your handler definition can be anything intersected with `ExampleEvent` so you need to define your handler type like this :

```
const handlers: {
  [K in EventType] : (event: ExampleEvent & any) => void
} = {
  login: (event: LoginEvent) =>
    console.log('user logged in', event.payload.userId),
  newMessage: (event: NewMessageEvent) =>
    console.log('new message', event.payload.messageId),
};
```

To make `event` to accept types `LoginEvent` and `NewMessageEvent`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAKuaBeKByANgewHMBLRbKAHx0QgHcBZCAZyYENCJsBuAWACh+-UJFgAPVgFswuCPCTAoWAN78oUYRABcsBMjSRefNWFYgCrACYB+bQFdEAa0T5aiQwF9Dgo+vRQAMkSkcsiKYpLSsroKAGRQKj4a2nhBZIbGpuYW2glqarZMEABOAJLZUEzARaSE6VCe-A0CfBpQAHJ0jCzsUfJhMOJSMiGx8aq+kMk0DMxsHNzjJmb4ljnjahKzPWXaldWIteNNTfwAxviIlVAEJIgjUNqBt-fK40k4N6TYADSLmSvlXJ5ArFHY4VgAI1OPyOvz4Jz450uCmmXTmvVC2g6M26HBeY0S6CmnS28zhGWWqwJeSgm1xEDB2Eh0PJ9ThCKRVwg0SYYQA2p87tFvlBUaSMcAALpeREXK4AC1YiAsMiKTDWPj5AGkoKQdPJ9BBJQ8oAAKbnybQDCLDaJQOJKkAASkUAD4oHB8MQLI0wkDBdpzdFHqkRi6MK71lBOfgZAA6G6m7AgorXIgcCy6sgii3IONLLJxlNlJ2ssX0wO54BYkn0sNuqMx+OJ7DTWnin5QKv5-6WON09El9kyqtMOMAM3wRRgrFO8qDfQj1KgiuVqqYfO7GklC+QTq4UAA9IeoPgHI190A)